# Tools for georeferencing PDF's

Tags: qgis, gdal, geospatial-pdf

5 years ago I exported all our PDF record drawings to TIFF and georeferenced them using Esri Arc Desktop. This added the .tfw file associated with georeferenced images without modifying the original images. This allowed them to be opened as regular images without being rotated, squared off, and filled in with "no data" pixels around the edges. This is important because it allows for better viewing in image software and edits made to the tiff (notes drawings etc..) don't ruin the georeferencing and still allows them to act like a raster data layer in AutoCAD, Esri, QGIS, and other GIS/Spatial Software.
When I try this with PDF's the result is a PDF that is altered in such a way that it is difficult to view as a standard PDF (it is rotated and squared off with a "no data" pixels around the outside).
Is there a way to reference the PDF so that it acts in the same way an image does when associated with a .tfw file? Can it be done using QGIS or other free/open source product?

Comment: Georeferencing will often rotate and/or rescale an image; that's what georeferencing *is*.  If you're looking for a non-georeferencing form of georeferencing, you might be looking for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Global Mapper natively reads PDF and  geopdf and writes GeoPDF. You can georeference and save in whatever format you want

Answer (score 1):

Rasters are always rectangular, with their edges oriented with the axes of their coordinate reference system. Georeferencing an image usually rotates that image. If you rotate a rectangular image, you then have to add a nodata border around it to make the output into a rectangle with its edges oriented with its coordinate reference system.

[image]

The same is true if the image has to be warped or distorted in the georeferencing process. If the final georeferenced image has non-straight edges, a border must be added in order to create straight edges.

To avoid adding a border around a raster when you georeference it, the trick is to find a coordinate reference system that doesn't require the image to be rotated and distorted very much. You can do this if the original image was produced as a "to scale" map in a defined coordinate reference system. Otherwise the final image will necessarily be warped  and/or rotated, and it will therefore require a border.

Comment: This isn't always true, it depends on the method of georeferencing used; 5 years ago I exported all the PDF's to tiff and georeferenced them using esri Arc Desktop and the it didn't modify the tiff's in this way. You can still open them in an image viewer and view them as you depict it in square one. Basically what happens is that Arc (or QGIS) creates 4 (or 3 in QGIS) files that give the raster a spatial orientation of which are read by the GIS to scale, rotate and project the data, but the original dataset is unaltered.

Comment: Since Arc Desktop 9.x you also had the option of preventing outputs from looking like figure 3 when exporting by selecting "Use Original Dataset" radial under the Extent Option. This essential allowed you to export the raster like your square in figure 2 and did away with the figure 3 output. You can still export to a figure 3 looking output by selecting "Use Current Data Frame" in the Extent Options. Now this is Esri and not QGIS however I can load all those georeferenced in Esri files in QGIS without the figure 3 effect and am certain I exported from Q without it too in QGIS 2.x versions.